# how to fix this problem in CNN using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, speech-recognition

I have five folders and each folder has 25 datapoints. We partition the data into training and testing splits such that 75% of the data is for training and the remaining 25% is for testing. Here is my code

```
    batch_size = 128
    epochs = 50
    model= create_model()
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
early_stopping=callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=10, verbose=0, mode='min')

filepath="top_model.h5"

checkpoint = callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')

callbacks_list = [early_stopping,checkpoint]
model.fit(trainX, trainY,shuffle=True,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(testX, testY),callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

And executing the above code shows this error

```
Train on 1560 samples, validate on 520 samples
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-8fd14ef9b0fb> in <module>
      3           epochs=epochs,
      4           verbose=1,
----> 5           validation_data=(testX, testY),callbacks=callbacks_list)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1237                                         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
   1238                                         validation_steps=validation_steps,
-> 1239                                         validation_freq=validation_freq)
   1240 
   1241     def evaluate(self,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, fit_function, fit_inputs, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_function, val_inputs, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq)
    139     indices_for_conversion_to_dense = []
    140     for i in range(len(feed)):
--> 141         if issparse(fit_inputs[i]) and not K.is_sparse(feed[i]):
    142             indices_for_conversion_to_dense.append(i)
    143 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2):

The error "list index out of range" is due to accessing the list index that doesn't exist. try changing the batch size = 16 and check (since your data size is < 128 data points).

Answer (score 2):

This is because:

since size is not fixed, the available index is greater than the assigned index for a list(available index > assigned index).

If you try to access the empty or None element by pointing available index of list, Then you will get the List index out of range error.
for example:

> > x = list(‘1234’)
> >
> > x

Output=[‘1’ , ‘2’ , ‘3’, ‘4’]

> > length = len(x)

Output=4

> > x[length]

Output=Index Error: list index out of range

since the x[length] starts from 0 it must be 3 so it prints the forth word.this is the same i your case.

Comment: Ahmar Ali so where ever you have added [i] please check weather the array at the i exists or not this is purely a trail and error

Comment: What changes do where I added[i]?